# Meaning of strange class name from an object

Tags: scala

```
object Initialization {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val list = Traversable(1,2,4,5)

    //list.foreach(println)

    println( list.getClass.getSimpleName )

  }

}
```

It prints `$colon$colon`, but I expected something like `List`. What does this obscure name mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because [`List`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) is a sealed superclass that is over case class [`::`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/%24colon%24colon.html) and object [`Nil`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Nil%24.html) (see the *known subclasses* section under the List documentation). `::` is pronounced *cons*, being named after the list cons operator in most traditional functional programming languages.

Since your list head is *actually* an instance of the `::` case class, and Scala uses name mangling to represent non-word class names on the JVM, you end up with `$colon$colon` when you use reflection to get the name.

**Update:** I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to use the class name for, but you might be able to use [`stringPrefix`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/GenTraversableLike.html#stringPrefix%3aString) instead. It's defined for anything extending [`GenTraversableLike`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/GenTraversableLike.html), which will be pretty much every Scala collection type.

If you're trying to do control flow with the class name, you should probably try something else. Pattern matching would work nicely, e.g.:

```
xs match {
  list: List[_] => // do list stuff
  set: Set[_] => // do set stuff
}
```

Comment: `::` denotes a `List` with a `head` and a `tail`, `Nil` represents the empty list.

Comment: but when evaluate it in console it shows List:
val list = Traversable(1,2,4,5)
list: Traversable[Int] = List(1, 2, 4, 5)

Comment: what you see in console is inferred type of list (Traversable) and a string representation (List) from toString

Comment: @ses - That's because the method you're calling to get your list has a return type of `Traversable`, and the the `toString` method for `List` uses a `stringPrefix` of `List`. You can look at the generic [toString method implementation in TraversableLike](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L609) to see how it works. None of that changes the fact that the underlying classes are instances of `::` and `Nil`.

Comment: @ses - If you're trying to pick a control path based on the class name I think you're better off using something else. See my update above for a pattern matching example.